# How do I display a PHP object's properties in html?

Tags: php

```
class Student
{}

$student = new Student();
```

If `$student` has functions:

```
    getFirstName();
    getLastName();
```

QUESTION:
How do I display the return value of those functions in HTML?

Thanks.

Comment: Show us more code. What have you tried so far? What does your html php code looks like?

Comment: in `.html` extension no php code will work. it must be `.php` extension.Thanks

Comment: This is a really basic question, and this is not a good place to ask it. For your sake, watch some tutorials and learn OOP in PHP step by step from someone.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.print.php Use print, and object operators http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php

Answer (score 0):

What you probably need is the __toString() method.

http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php#language.oop5.magic.tostring